# Access file from jar via native code

Tags: java, jar, java-native-interface

I have an applet which contains some images, regular java classes and class, which uses C code via JNI. All this is included in jar file, and the appropriate dll is located somewhere on a harddrive. In C code I have to read a bitmap from the applet(jar). I know that it is simple to access this file from java via getResourceAsStream() method, but can I do it from native code?

I understand that I can pass the bytes of the bitmap to native code as a workaround, but it requires some rewriting, so I would like to avoid this.

So, is there any way to access files from within jar via native code, executed by class belonging to this jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just [call the appropriate Java methods](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html).